# Bad auto weight paints

Tags: weight-painting, rigify

[image]

Why are these rigify auto weight paints so bad. Other parts of the body work fine, i didnt have this problem before with the same model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The normals are flipped on the pants. You need to turn off the *Solidify* modifier to see it.**

[image: flipped normals on the pants]

To fix it switch to *Edit* mode, select the legs (<kbd>L</kbd>), and flip the normals (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> *Normals > Flip*). In *Object* mode, consider to apply the scale to the model (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *Scale*). Rebind the mesh to the armature.

Last but not least, make sure the *Solidify* modifier is added after the *Armature* modifier so the *Armature* modifier uses the original mesh to deform.

[image: fixed normals]