# Bone Heat Weighting Error, Trying to Rig Model

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, pose-mode

I'm trying to add a rig to my mesh, but I'm receiving an error every time I try to add these bones to my model.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)

Comment: That's the most canonical answer to bone heat failures on the site; the full range of causes is described in multiple answers.

Comment: There are 72 duplicated vertices (do a key M > *Merge by Distance* in *Edit* mode) and faces are flipped. *Recalculate Outside* (Shift+N) does not fix them all. Check the knees and lower legs. You need to flip the faces manually. Also, the *Subdivision Surface* modifier should be below the *Armature* modifier.

Comment: You also should apply at least the *Rotation* and *Scale* to the armature (Ctrl+A in *Object* mode) before you bind the mesh to it. I would apply the *Rotation*, *Scale*, and *Location* to the mesh, too. Have a look here for the details: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/255069/107598