my mesh is warping a bunch after rigging
ive never rigged anything before so if there's anything glaringly wrong with this lmk. theres a bunch of warping when im posing so i feel like i did something majorly wrong. i followed this tutorial. Rigging wont work
i did the dummy mesh, automatic weights, etccc
so maybe i misunderstood something. i would really appreciate the help. my original file is here (the stuff being used is on the veryy bottom of the outliner):



Please share your Blend file using the official web site rather than using an external site where it will not be available to future BSE users.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

The screenshot (other than not having enough clothes on) looks fine? Maybe a little stretching of the arm but idk what the problem is. I hope it is more obvious in the file… Will check it out later if I can.

@TheLabCat i think it is much more obvious in the file so yes pls if u can i would really appreciate it :)

The body mesh has flipped normals. Same problem as here (point 2) https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/273304/107598 and here https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/255069/107598. You can do Recalculate Outside (Shift+N) in Edit mode to fix it. Then rebind the mesh to the armature with automatic weights and it should work.

@Blunder Please flag this question as a duplicate if you believe it to be.

This question is similar to: Rigify armature won't move my mesh. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
